# JSF 2.0, RAD 8 & Websphere Application Server 7.0

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to run a JSF 2.0 application with Mojarra 2.0 implementation. I need to change the Web Module class loading policy of the .war file to PARENT_LAST, so that WAS doesn't load the default configuration. I want the JSF 2.o implementation to be loaded from WEB-INF/lib folder. However RAD does not allow me to change the settings to PARENT_LAST in admin Console. ( It's disabled )

It works fine,when the class loader policy is set using shared libarary references and set at the server level. However I don't want that.

I would like this to be loaded at the "Web Module" level.

Can anyone help how to change to PARENT_LAST that using admin console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I changed the deployment.xml file directly to include warClassLoaderPolicy="SINGLE" and changed the mode of the classloader element to "PARENT_LAST". It loaded the Mojarra JSF 2.0 implemention.